Dynamic buckets with limited percentage capacity - Power Bi Visualization
Im looking for an idea how to create some kind of 4 equal buckets. Every single bucket is limited up to  25 percent of  %GT Count of Ticket_ID I wish to display them dynamically. I mean would like to add different number of accounts to every bucket(multiply variations), although not to exceed 25 percent and be able to supposedly steward, adding/ removing to another bucket(chart? matrix? maybe something else. Has anyone tried something similar and would like to advise?
TIA.
Base on -> 

pls see if this is what you want
this is the sample data I used



ID
value




a
100


b
200


c
300


d
400


e
500


f
600


g
700



Measure = sum('Table'[value])

PROPORTION = [Measure]/CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[value]),ALL('Table'))

P2 =
VAR _PROPORTION = [PROPORTION]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [PROPORTION],
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table'[ID] ), [PROPORTION] >= _PROPORTION )
    )

bucket =
SWITCH ( TRUE (), [P2] <= 0.25, "A", [P2] <= 0.5, "B", [P2] <= 0.75, "C", "D" )


